# Representing types and storing local variables?

Tags: memory, assembly, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler, and whilst I understand what I would need to do to handle built-in types like an `Int` that would fit into a register and could be pushed onto the stack or whatever nicely, I don't know how to approach user-defined types (the language is predominantly object-oriented), so given the example of this:

```
class Color
{
    Color(Int r, Int g, Int b)
        r
        g
        b
    { }
    method GetR() Int
    {
        return r
    }
}
```

Where `r`, `g` and `b` automatically become member variables of type `Int`. How do I handle instances of `Color` in, for example, `GetR()`.

**My thought**

The best way to do this, I think, is to reserve a register (or perhaps a space in the stack frame of each method would be better?) to hold a pointer to `this`. Then, if you wanted to implement `GetR()`, assuming `r10` held this pointer and the `r` member started at that address exactly, you could generate:

```
_G_Color_GetR:
    mov rax, [r10]
    ret
```

Is this a good way to approach the problem, and if not, how do other compilers for other languages approach it?

Comment: Yes, that's typical implementation - pass `this` like a parameter. Either as if it was extra first parameter or through a designated register.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much!